# Onmouseover/out deactivate and reactivate in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search function that does 3 things:

1) first, when a user hover over the icon, it should change the icon, and the color of border around it as well:

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbox">
  <img id="search" src="Icons/magnifier2.png"    
       onmouseover="this.src='Icons/magnifier.png'"
       onmouseout="this.src='Icons/magnifier2.png'"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchbox #search {
  display: inline;
  border: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.searchbox #search:hover {
  display: inline;
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

So far so good. In this bit, im unsure why the image isnt applied any transition at all when hovered... Is there a way in which you can change color on a single .png icon, instead of juggling between two .pngs?

2) The user is supposed to click on this icon, whereafter it expands with a new icon and a changed border width (padding-left: 130px;). Here goes the following jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
  var search = $("#search");

  search.click(function () {
    search.attr("src", "Icons/magnifier.png").css({ 
      "border": "2px", 
      "border-style": "solid", 
      "border-color": "#808080", 
      "padding-left": "130px", 
      "transition": "all 500ms" });
  });
});
```

3) When the user clicks on the HTML body, the border should slide back to normal position and apply the original CSS:

```
$('html').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'search') {
    $("#search").attr("src", "Icons/magnifier2.png");
    $("#search").removeAttr('style');;
  }
});
```

My issue is, the HTML onmouseover/out shown in the top of my post, is still active when the function is fired upon clicking the icon.(if i place my mouse inside and outside the expanded border, it still changes the icon.)

My idea of an easy fix:

It would be a lot easier if the :hover parameter in the CSS could change both the color of the .png and the border, however i've been searching alot for this specific solution, and it doesnt seem to be available!

The second solution would be to add some kind of code in the jQuery, search.click(function() that deactivates the onmouseover/out and reactivates it in the 2'nd .click(function().

I hope im clear enough with my question.

- How do i overcome this onmouseover/out issue?

I've added a jsfiddle just for you to see my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/bfytnbs3/

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but all the properties inside `:hover` css are redundant except `border`, and that can be simplified to `border-color: #808080`

Comment: i just realized that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be a lot easier if the :hover parameter in the CSS could
>   change both the color of the .png and the border, however i've been
>   searching alot for this specific solution, and it doesnt seem to be
>   available!

You can accomplish that using a CSS sprite.  More reading is here:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Basically, you'd have one magnifier.png image that would have both states for the icon.  Then you'd use some CSS to switch between them.

```
.searchbox {
    background: url('magnifier.png') 0px 0px;
}

.searchbox:hover {
    background: url('magnifier.png') 0px -25px;
}
```

In this example, you'd have a sprite image that was 25px by 50px, with each state of the image being 25px by 25px.

Hope that helps!

Edit to add:  Here is a JS Fiddle Example so you can see how it works:

### https://jsfiddle.net/s51zjre4/1/

Comment: Thank you, i will look into that :D can i disable my :hover css when the jquery function is fired?

Comment: Yes, the best way would be to toggle classes on the element you don't want to have the hover styles.  I've updated my answer with a JS Fiddle example so you can see how it works.  :-)  Let me know if that is what you were looking for.